# Change text of cancel button in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, cancel-button

I've created an AlertDialog like so:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

And then I've set the buttons:

```
return builder.setTitle(titleText).setView(mDialogLayout)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).create();
```

Is there a way I can change the "NegativeButton" to say something other than "Cancel"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this:

```
return builder.setTitle(titleText).setView(mDialogLayout)
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).create();
```

to:

```
return builder.setTitle(titleText).setView(mDialogLayout)
                .setNegativeButton("Text you need", null).create();
```

[setNegativeButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setNegativeButton(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)) method's first argument can take your text.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply provide your own text resource to the first argument of setNegativeButton.  Currently you are giving it and Android platform string.